# SyntaxError al lanzar una aplicación Django recién creada

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Acabo de crear un proyecto con Django

```
django-admin startproject portfolio
```

Pero al lanzar la mia applicacion obtengo un SyntaxError. Por lo tanto no me recuerdo hacar cualquier cosa con el codigo:

```
(dja_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Django\portfolio>py manage.py
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Aqui esta el script culpable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "portfolio.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

## Actualizacion

Tambien pensé que la causa fue la version de python pero parece que el problema esta tambien con python3:

```
(dja_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Django\portfolio>py -V
Python 3.8.5

(dja_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Django\portfolio>py manage.py
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## pip freeze

```
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.3
configparser==4.0.2
crayons==0.3.0
dash==1.7.0
dash-auth==1.3.2
dash-core-components==1.6.0
dash-daq==0.3.1
dash-html-components==1.0.2
dash-renderer==1.2.2
dash-table==4.5.1
docutils==0.16
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
Flask-SeaSurf==0.2.2
future==0.18.2
idna==2.8
intel-openmp==2019.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mkl==2019.0
plotly==4.5.2
pyprimes==0.1
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.14.0
statistics==1.0.3.5
tqdm==4.46.0
ua-parser==0.10.0
urllib3==1.25.8
webdriver-manager==2.4.0
Werkzeug==1.0.0
```

## pip3 freeze

```
absl-py==0.9.0
aiofiles==0.4.0
aiohttp==3.6.2
APScheduler==3.6.3
asgiref==3.2.10
astor==0.8.1
astropy==4.0.1.post1
async-generator==1.10
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bleach==3.1.5
bokeh==2.0.1
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.12.33
botocore==1.15.33
Brotli==1.0.7
bs4==0.0.1
cachetools==4.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.1
click-plugins==1.1.1
cligj==0.5.0
cloudpickle==1.2.2
colorama==0.4.3
colorclass==2.2.0
coloredlogs==10.0
colorhash==1.0.2
configparser==5.0.0
confuse==1.3.0
crayons==0.3.0
cryptography==2.8
cvxopt==1.2.5
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.14
dash==1.11.0
dash-auth==1.3.2
dash-core-components==1.9.1
dash-html-components==1.0.3
dash-renderer==1.4.0
dash-table==4.6.2
dask==2.13.0
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
deprecation==2.1.0
dialogflow==0.4.0
distributed==2.13.0
Django==3.1
dnspython==1.16.0
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.15.2
entrypoints==0.3
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Compress==1.5.0
Flask-SeaSurf==0.2.2
fpdf==1.7.2
fsspec==0.7.1
future==0.17.1
gast==0.2.2
gensim==3.8.3
geojson==2.5.0
google-api-core==1.17.0
google-auth==1.14.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
grpcio==1.28.1
h11==0.8.1
h2==3.2.0
h5py==2.10.0
HeapDict==1.0.1
hpack==3.0.0
hstspreload==2020.3.31
htmlmin==0.1.12
httplib2==0.17.0
httptools==0.1.1
httpx==0.9.3
humanfriendly==8.1
hyperframe==5.2.0
idna==2.6
ImageHash==4.1.0
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
intel-openmp==2019.0
ipykernel==5.3.0
ipython==7.16.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.17.1
Jinja2==2.11.1
jmespath==0.9.5
joblib==0.15.1
Js2Py==0.70
jsonpickle==1.3
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter-client==6.1.5
jupyter-core==4.6.3
kafka-python==1.4.7
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
llvmlite==0.33.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==4.5.0
Markdown==3.2.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.2
mattermostwrapper==2.2
missingno==0.4.2
mistune==0.8.4
mkl==2019.0
msgpack==1.0.0
multidict==4.7.5
munch==2.5.0
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.7
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
networkx==2.4
notebook==6.0.3
num2words==0.5.10
numba==0.50.1
numpy==1.18.5
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
opt-einsum==3.2.0
packaging==20.3
pandas==1.0.3
pandas-profiling==2.8.0
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.7.0
partd==1.1.0
phik==0.10.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pika==1.1.0
Pillow==7.1.0
pipwin==0.5.0
plotly==4.6.0
prometheus-client==0.8.0
prompt-toolkit==2.0.10
protobuf==3.11.3
psutil==5.7.0
pusher==2.0.1
pyaml==19.12.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pydot==1.4.1
Pygments==2.6.1
pyjsparser==2.7.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pykernels==0.0.4
pykwalify==1.7.0
pymongo==3.8.0
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pyparsing==2.4.6
PyPrind==2.11.2
pyproj==2.6.1.post1
pyreadline==2.1
pyrsistent==0.16.0
pySmartDL==1.3.3
python-crfsuite==0.9.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.8.2
python-engineio==3.11.2
python-socketio==4.4.0
python-telegram-bot==11.1.0
pytz==2019.3
PyWavelets==1.1.1
pywin32==228
pywinpty==0.5.7
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==19.0.1
questionary==1.5.1
rasa-sdk==1.9.0
redis==3.4.1
requests==2.24.0
requests-futures==1.0.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
retrying==1.3.3
rfc3986==1.3.2
rocketchat-API==0.6.36
rsa==4.0
ruamel.yaml==0.15.100
s3transfer==0.3.3
sanic==19.12.2
Sanic-Cors==0.10.0.post3
sanic-jwt==1.3.2
Sanic-Plugins-Framework==0.9.2
scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.10.1
selenium==3.141.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.14.0
sklearn-crfsuite==0.3.6
slackclient==2.5.0
smart-open==2.1.0
sniffio==1.1.0
snips-nlu-parsers==0.4.3
snips-nlu-utils==0.9.1
sortedcontainers==2.1.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.15
sqlparse==0.3.1
tabulate==0.8.7
tangled-up-in-unicode==0.0.6
tblib==1.6.0
tensorboard==2.1.1
tensorflow-addons==0.8.3
tensorflow-hub==0.7.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.3
terminaltables==3.1.0
testpath==0.4.4
tika==1.24
toolz==0.10.0
tornado==6.0.4
tqdm==4.47.0
traitlets==4.3.3
typeguard==2.7.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.1
tzlocal==2.0.0
ua-parser==0.10.0
ujson==1.35
urllib3==1.22
visions==0.4.4
wcwidth==0.1.9
webdriver-manager==2.5.3
webencodings==0.5.1
webexteamssdk==1.1.1
websockets==8.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.12.1
yarl==1.4.2
zict==2.0.0
zipp==3.1.0
```

## Actualizacion

Empecé de nuevo con un nuevo entorno pero con el mismo proyecto:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Django\portfolio>virtualenv myvenv
Using base prefix 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3'
  No LICENSE.txt / LICENSE found in source
New python executable in C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Django\portfolio\myvenv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Django\portfolio>myvenv\Scripts\activate

(myvenv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Django\portfolio>pip install django
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by SS
LError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError
("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

No puedo descargar Django. Deberia intentar con pip3?

Comment: Ami me suele dar ese error cuando lo ejecuto con Python 2....

Comment: Tu problema es que `django-admin` se esta ejecuto con python3 y seguramente tienes por defecto python2 en tu sistema, intenta ejecutando `python3 manage.py`

Comment: @JhoubertRincon si, tambien pensé esto, pero parece que es la misma error

Comment: @JulioCesar Si, intenté con py que es python3 pero me da el mismo error